check the column in data dump is it is matching with any string of patterns in another sheet using macro
I have a source file with ~20000 records in sheet "data" and a list of patterns identified in another sheet "pattern". The "data" sheet contains a column : description. I want to compare the description column with the strmatch column in pattern sheet and see if substring in description column match with any of the rows in strmatch column.
sample data for data sheet



Description
Expected output after running macro




sample is here
No Match found


data dump
data


Apple is fruitt
Apple


Appleis fruitt
Apple


fruitt
No Match found


fruits
fruits



sample data for pattern sheet



strmatch




data


fruits


Apple



output expected to be printed in a new column in the data sheet
No match found if not matching with any of string in pattern sheet else the matched string from the pattern sheet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function

Would you expect it to match on "apple" as well as "Apple"?  Would "Pineapple" and "grapple" count as a match for apple?

Yes, case insensitive and any part of the string which is in the list of patterns are considered

This will do what you need:
Sub findmatches()

    Dim r As Long, input_text As String, output_text As String, search_text, compare_method As VbCompareMethod, rgStrMatch As Range
    
    compare_method = vbBinaryCompare 'set this to vbTextCompare for case insensitive searching
    
    Set rgStrMatch = Range("strmatch") 'this could be dynamically found if needed
    
    For r = 2 To 7 'this could be dynamically found if needed
        input_text = Cells(r, 1)
        output_text = ""
        For Each search_text In rgStrMatch.Cells
            If InStr(1, input_text, search_text, compare_method) Then output_text = output_text & " " & search_text
        Next
        If output_text = "" Then output_text = "No match found"
        Cells(r, 2) = Trim(output_text)
    Next

End Sub

It is based on your sample data being 6 rows (2 to 7). You may want to change this to dynamically find the last row of data. It also assumes your strmatch table is a named range of cells called strmatch. You could instead also dynamically find this range. There are questions previously answered on here for how to achieve this.
Result:


Thank you , I am getting and error "method range of object _global failed" in the line :Set rgStrMatch = Range("strmatch"). can you help please

you need to name your strmatch list. alternatively you could just supply the range with Set rgStrMatch = Range("F2:F4") (based on my result image)
